# After submitting a form i get an error "Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found."

Tags: php, html, materialize, laravel-5.5

I'm new with laravel and now i making some small project. I have a form, after the submit button pressed i got this error message "Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found."

Is there anything wrong about my code?
Please help me to fix this issue, so i can continuing the project.

Thanks in advice

view blade, i named it index.blade.php

```
<div class="col m7 s12">
        <form method="submit" action="post">
          {{ csrf_field() }}
          <div class="card-panel">
            <h5>Please Fill Out This Form</h5>
            <div class="input-field">
              <input type="text" name="name" id="name" required class="validate">
              <label for="name">Name</label>
            </div>
            <div class="input-field">
              <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="validate">
              <label for="email">Email</label>
            </div>
            <div class="input-field">
              <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone">
              <label for="phone">Phone</label>
            </div>
            <div class="input-field">
              <textarea name="message" id="message" class="materialize-textarea"></textarea>
              <label for="message">Message</label>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn" blue darken-1>Send</button>
          </div>
        </form>
```

controller, i named it LayoutController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DB;

class LayoutController extends Controller

    {
        /**
         * Display a listing of the resource.
         *
         * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
         */
        public function index()
        {
            //
            return view('layouts/index');
        }

        public function submit(Request $request)
        {
            $name = $req->input('name');
            $email = $req->input('email');
            $phone = $req->input('phone');
            $message = $req->input('message');

            $data = array('name'=>$name,"email"=>$email,"phone"=>$phone,"message"=>$message);

            $data->save();
            return Redirect::to('/layouts/index');
        }
```

routes web.php

```
Route::get('/', 'LayoutController@index');

Route::post('/submit', 'LayoutController@submit');
```

Comment: to which url are you going?

Comment: return Redirect::to('/layouts/index');
Try this : return Redirect::to('layouts/index');

Comment: hai brother form method is POST and action will be your route 
method="post" action="{{ url('/submit') }}"

Answer (score 0):

Your form method should be `POST` and action should be `/submit`

```
<form method="POST" action="/submit">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <div class="card-panel">
      <h5>Please Fill Out This Form</h5>
      <div class="input-field">
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" required class="validate">
        <label for="name">Name</label>
      </div>
      <div class="input-field">
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="validate">
        <label for="email">Email</label>
      </div>
      <div class="input-field">
        <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone">
        <label for="phone">Phone</label>
      </div>
      <div class="input-field">
        <textarea name="message" id="message" class="materialize-textarea"></textarea>
        <label for="message">Message</label>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn" blue darken-1>Send</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('submit') }}">
```

Answer (score 0):

The Error you're getting is because the wrong `<form>` tag attributes

> action => 'The route or page or class method that'll process the form
>   information'
>
> method => 'This the URI HTTP verb used to transport information, you
>   can either use POST(sending data as http payload) or GET(sending data
>   as query string)

changing the `<form>` tag like this will solve your issue

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ url('/submit') }}">
```

Answer (score 0):

The form method should be `POST` and the `action` will be your route:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ url('/submit') }}">
```

Comment: Can you explain that further? What makes you think that this code solves the problem?

Comment: Hai 
In his code he uses
method="submit" action="post"

Comment: Please add all such explanation to the answer itself, not to the comment section

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="col m7 s12">
    <form method="POST" action="{{url('/submit')}}">
      {{ csrf_field() }}
      <div class="card-panel">
        <h5>Please Fill Out This Form</h5>
        <div class="input-field">
          <input type="text" name="name" id="name" required class="validate">
          <label for="name">Name</label>
        </div>
        <div class="input-field">
          <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="validate">
          <label for="email">Email</label>
        </div>
        <div class="input-field">
          <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone">
          <label for="phone">Phone</label>
        </div>
        <div class="input-field">
          <textarea name="message" id="message" class="materialize-textarea"></textarea>
          <label for="message">Message</label>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn" blue darken-1>Send</button>
      </div>
    </form>
```